# Getting Error code -1120 while creating table in the SAP B1

Tags: c#, json, exception, sapb1, sap-business-one-di-api

`Hello All,
I am trying to create a table in the SAP B1. But I am getting an error code "-1120".
For creating a table I have fetched a data from the json file.
And by using that data I tried to create the tables in the SAP B1.
But I am getting an error code "-1120".

Here is the code

```
            string text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\vijay\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestAddon_03\TestAddon_03\json1.json");
            var tableInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TableInfo>(text);

            try
            {
                foreach (var table in tableInfo.tables)
                {
                    string tbName = table.tableName;
                    string tbDis = table.tableDescription;
                    string tbType = table.tableType;

                    GC.Collect();
                    SAPbobsCOM.UserTablesMD objUserTableMD = (SAPbobsCOM.UserTablesMD)oCompany.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.oUserTables);
                    objUserTableMD.TableName = tbName;
                    objUserTableMD.TableDescription = tbDis;

                    switch (tbType)
                    {
                        case "Document":
                            objUserTableMD.TableType = SAPbobsCOM.BoUTBTableType.bott_Document;
                            break;
                        case "MasterData":
                            objUserTableMD.TableType = SAPbobsCOM.BoUTBTableType.bott_MasterData;
                            break;
                        case "NoObject":
                            objUserTableMD.TableType = SAPbobsCOM.BoUTBTableType.bott_NoObject;
                            break;
                        default:
                            Application.SBO_Application.MessageBox("Invalid Table Type");
                            break;
                    }

                    int result = objUserTableMD.Add();

                    //Application.SBO_Application.MessageBox(Convert.ToString(result));

                    if(result != 0)
                    {
                        Application.SBO_Application.MessageBox("Table Not Created" + "\n --------- \n" + oCompany.GetLastErrorDescription() );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Application.SBO_Application.MessageBox("Table Created");
                        foreach (var field in table.fields)
                        {
                            string fieldNm = field.fieldName;
                            string fieldType = field.fieldType;
                            int fieldSize = field.fieldSize;

                            SAPbobsCOM.UserFieldsMD objUserFieldsMD = (SAPbobsCOM.UserFieldsMD)oCompany.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.oUserFields);
                            objUserFieldsMD = null;
                            objUserFieldsMD.TableName = tbName;
                            objUserFieldsMD.Name = field.fieldName;

                            switch (fieldType)
                            {
                                case "Numeric":
                                    objUserFieldsMD.Type = SAPbobsCOM.BoFieldTypes.db_Numeric;
                                    break;
                                case "String":
                                    objUserFieldsMD.Type = SAPbobsCOM.BoFieldTypes.db_Alpha;
                                    break;
                                case "Date":
                                    objUserFieldsMD.Type = SAPbobsCOM.BoFieldTypes.db_Date;
                                    break;
                                case "Float":
                                    objUserFieldsMD.Type = SAPbobsCOM.BoFieldTypes.db_Float;
                                    break;
                                case "Memo":
                                    objUserFieldsMD.Type = SAPbobsCOM.BoFieldTypes.db_Memo;
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    Application.SBO_Application.MessageBox("Invalid FieldType");
                                    break;
                            }

                            objUserFieldsMD.Size = field.fieldSize;
                            int fieldResult = objUserFieldsMD.Add();

                            if (fieldResult != 0)
                            {
                                Application.SBO_Application.MessageBox("Fields Not Created");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Application.SBO_Application.MessageBox("Fields Created");
                            }
                        }

                    

                       // Application.SBO_Application.MessageBox(tbName + " " + tbDis + " " + tbType + " " + fieldNm + " " + fieldType + " " + fieldSize);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception Create)
            {
                Application.SBO_Application.MessageBox(Create.ToString());
            }
```

---

**And This is a sample json file**

```
{
    "tables": [
        {
            "tableName": "SAMP1",
            "tableDescription": "SampleTable 1",
            "tableType": "Document",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "fieldName": "CF1",
                    "fieldType": "String",
                    "fieldSize": 100
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "tableName": "SAPM2",
            "tableDescription": "SampleTable 2",
            "tableType": "MasterData",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "fieldName": "CF2",
                    "fieldType": "Numeric",
                    "fieldSize": 8
                },
                {
                    "fieldName": "CF3",
                    "fieldType": "String",
                    "fieldSize": 50
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am getting the error at the below line:

Application.SBO_Application.MessageBox("Table Not Created" + "\n --------- \n" + oCompany.GetLastErrorDescription() );

Error:

SAPbobsCOM.ICompany.GetLastErrorDescription returend "Ref Count for this object is higher then 0".

Comment: You have to post an error message  and show the line where this error happened

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `objUserTableMD` to null and do another garbage collection after creating the table and before adding its fields. You might also need to call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject()` on the reference.

B1 only allows a single instance of schema modifying objects to exist.

Comment: Hello Daz,
Thank you for the answer.
I tried to set the objUserTableMD to 'null' but I am getting an error like -> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Do you have any other method to creating the table in the SAP B1. Can you please share me the code.

Comment: You have another error in the code. After creating the table you have a objUserFieldsMD = null between reinitialising the object and using it.